# CakePHP JSON Rendering

Tags: json, cakephp

I cannot for the life of me work out why

```
$xml['interaction']['twitteraccount'] = 'hello';
```

Causes my JSON output to render as HTML rather than JSON. I've tried all options and played around for a while. Surely I'm missing something? As soon as I take that line out again, it renders as JSON!

```
public function lifestream()
{
    $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json' ); 

    $this->set('interactions', $this->Interaction->find('all'));

    $xmlArray = array();

    foreach($this->Interaction->find('all') as $interaction) {
        $sourceexploded = explode("/",$interaction['Interaction']['source']);

        if($sourceexploded[0] == "twitter") {
            $xml['interaction']['source'] = $sourceexploded[0];
            $xml['interaction']['twitteraccount'] = 'hello';
        } else {
            $xml['interaction']['source'] = $interaction['Interaction']['source'];
        }

        $xml['interaction']['timestamp'] = $interaction['Interaction']['timestamp'];
        $xml['interaction']['receivedfrom'] = $interaction['Interaction']['receivedfrom'];
        $xmlArray[] = $xml;
    }

    echo json_encode($xmlArray);
```

Comment: See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: I've already used and looked at the manual numerous times... Is there something specifically I should be looking at rather than 'the XML and JSON' area of the manual...

Comment: Well, start reading the link I gave you, your code clearly doesn't look like what is described on that page so I doubt you read it properly. See Thibaults answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the JsonView.
In your route.php write: `Router::parseExtensions('json');`

In your controller you have to set the RequestHandler Component.

```
class SomeNameController{

 public $components = array('RequestHandler');

 public function lifestream(){
   $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json' ); 
   $this->set('interactions', $this->Interaction->find('all'));
   $xmlArray = array();
   foreach($this->Interaction->find('all') as $interaction) {
    /* do stuff */
    $xmlArray[] = $xml;
   }
   $this->set('data', $xmlArray);
   $this->set('_serialize', array(
            'data', 
    ));
 }
```

}

Try to go on "samename/lifestream.json" now or make an HTTP request with "Content-Type: application/json".

Look at : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Answer (score 0):

add this 2 line of code:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->autoRender = false;
```

The first line instructs the render to use an empty layout called ajax (you can find it on Views/Layouts/ajax.ctp

The second one instruct the render to not look for an view template (ctp file)

Then when you echo the json_encode it will rendered as xml